# Google Apps script txt file getDataAsString() returns � and square symbols between characters

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, character-encoding, google-drive-api, text-parsing

**CURRENTLY**

I have a `.txt` file which contains some data:

```
                      Z Financial

Company name of the tax subject :
```

I have a google script file to get the data from the `.txt` and convert into JSON format to paste into Google Sheet (like a manual import in Google Sheets would do)

Snippet:

```js
    let files = folder.getFiles();
    var file = files.next();
    var raw = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    console.log(raw);
    var data = Utilities.parseCsv(raw)
```

**ISSUE**

`console.log(raw)` is returning:
[image]

`data` variable the returns as array of length 1 with value: `��`  and nothing else.

From the `.txt` snippet above, I would (roughly) expect an array of length = 3, with lines as follows:

- Z Financial
- 
- Company name of the tax subject :

**NOTES**

- replacing default `UTF-8` encoding with `ISO-8859-1` doesn't fix the issue. Returns:
  [image]

**QUESTION**

What am I missing to get the txt parsed as a CSV?

Comment: Just because the file name contains ".txt" doesn't make it a text file.  If you click on the file in your Google Drive, and look at the "Details" pane on the right, does it state that it's a text file?  Did you create the text file?  If so, how did you create it?

Comment: @AlanWells, yes the right hand side pane in google drive has `type: Text` but I did not create the file. It's sent to me via email from an external software system.

Comment: Also realize that the file is not a CSV. If it's delimited, you'll need to pass delimiter along in your `Utilities.parseCsv()` call.

Comment: @Diego, need to get a workable string first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is not setting a charset. Try using the correct charset.

```
var charset = 'ISO-8859-1'; // This is just a suggestion to try first
var raw = file.getBlob().getDataAsString(charset);
```

NOTE: The OP mentioned in a comment that the charset used by their file is `UTF-16`.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getDataAsString(String)

Related

- [Google Apps Script Utilities.parseCsv() and replacement character - �](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35377021/1595451) (read this first)
- [How do I fix charset problems in .gs script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19976532/1595451)
- [diamond character(�) appeared after fetch url in google script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36657957/1595451)
- [Get encoding of a file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3710374/1595451)
- [How to find out the character set of a text file](https://superuser.com/q/123731/152004) (from Super User)
- [How to detect the encoding of a file?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/187169/233431) (from Software Engineering)

Comment: The default charset is `UTF-8`. I have already tried the alternative `ISO-8859-1`, which only replaced the � symbol, but not the square symbols.

Comment: @Wronski What is the charset used by your file?

Comment: perfect. I didn't realise Google Script supported other options. The encoding of the file was `UTF-16` and once I used that as a parameter it fixed the issue! Thank you :)